# Skeleton for Kotlin/native multiproject with dll library for backend and frontend app using it

Tags: kotlin, gradle, dll, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I'm trying to create a multiproject using Kotlin/native and gradle in IDEA that consists of:

- A backend subproject library. I want to use this library in frontend Kotlin app and also produce a native DLL that can be later used in other software. I doubt I'll need any platform specific behavior -- the most I'll interact with the system is read, write and watch a file for changes.
- A frontend jvm app in Kotlin using this library as required dependency. To be more precise I'm going to write a glfw app in Kotlin that will use this lib, but that's a detail you don't have to bother with.

I want to be able to:

- build DLL on it's own
- build an app that depends on library and rebuilds if needed when the lib changed.

I made a hyperlink trip over gradle docs, JetBrains examples and repos but I don't quite understand how to make a multiproject like that. Can someone provide a minimal working example of such a Hello World project?

Comment: What is wrong with this tutorial: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-library.html?

Comment: The problem was with setting up and understanding gradle multiprojects. Online tutorials are often obsolete dating back to 2016 or earlier, use Groovy or outdated Gradle versions with deprecated features. My personal experience with gradle docs is that they are hard to read, leave a lot "as an exercise for the reader" and lack TL;DR+example sections -- that's why to understand how to make a multiproject I had to waste some time reading them. RN I have a working project -- but I won't post an answer with example until I make sure that it's WAI and is more or less "a vertical slice".

Comment: I'm asking because one could construct a simple project with a structure like that as follows. Using IDEA Wizard, I created a Kotlin/JVM Application. Then I used `New -> Module` and chose to add the `Gradle -> Kotlin/Multiplatform`. In the new module, I set the `jvm` target. And in the original JVM Application I've just added a dependency like `implementation(project(":library"))`. Please correct me if I misinterpreted your question. I'm just trying to figure out the problem's root.

Comment: Using that aproach a weird file structure is created: https://imgur.com/FzsHyLw that also doesn't go well with gradle doc's - wrapper project with single settings.gradle.kts and subpdirectories with projects: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:adding_subprojects.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev I posted an answer on how I did what I wanted, but If there is a better /cleaner way (e.g. using wizard) I'm willing to accept the answer. I didn't find any fulling working wizard to generate a multiproject out of the box in IDEA without creating files by hand.

Comment: Your answer looks good to me. About the wizard: I'm not sure if this particular scenario should be implemented separately. See, this is a complex project consisting of several parts. Each one of them can be created using wizards. I can imagine some people would prefer to have these modules as independent projects and work with them individually.

Comment: I think the best option would be the following. You could file an issue at the Kotlin issue tracker with the feature request about this kind of wizard. Then the community and the developers would be able to discuss this approach publicly and figure out how useful it would be. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Right now this works for me in the initial stage of the project:

1. Use `gradle init` with `basic` type and kotlin DSL to generate a wrapper project
2. Add 2 modules with `New > Module > Gradle > Kotlin/Multiplatform and Kotlin/JVM`. That should add `include("...")` entries to root `settings.gradle.kts` At this point those modules will be empty with a single `build.gradle.kts` scripts
3. Root `build.gradle.kts` can be deleted - both library and app use their own
4. In the Multiplatform library setup at least one target for example like that:

   ```
   // rootProject/library/build.gradle.kts
   // ...
   kotlin {
      jvm() // used by jvm app
      sourceSets { /*...*/ }
   }
   ```
5. Now there should be no gradle errors and IDEA will detect the project properly - refresh gradle configuration (`CTRL+SHIFT+O`)
6. Create source directories for each module (because the modules rn): IDEA should hint the names of corresponding source sets (`src/<target>/<kotlin|resources>` etc.)
   [image: source sets hints]
7. So now just to link the app and library together in the the app's buildscript add the `implementation(project(":library"))` dependency
8. Of course don't forget to configure the library target for example using `linuxX64("native") { binaries { sharedLib {/*...*/ } } }` block in `kotlin` plugin when trying to generate a DLL

Now it should mostly work. The structure of a project I'm working on rn looks like that:

[image]